# Объединение запросов в mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mysql-workbench

Есть 2 запроса

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Subscriber_idSubscriber) AS "Кол-во абонентов сотовой мобильной связи"
FROM (
  SELECT idPlan, Communication_idCommunication
  FROM Plan
  WHERE Communication_idCommunication = 2 AND CommunicationDetails_idCommDetails = 2
) AS A
INNER JOIN Subscriptions AS B ON A.idPlan = B.Plan_idPlan;

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Subscriber_idSubscriber) AS "Количество абонентов [![широкоп][1]][1]олосного доступа к сети Интернет"
FROM (
  SELECT idPlan, Communication_idCommunication
  FROM Plan
  WHERE Communication_idCommunication = 3
) AS A
INNER JOIN Subscriptions AS B ON A.idPlan = B.Plan_idPlan;
```

Как их объединить, чтобы в итоге получилась похожая таблица?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA4ko.png

Comment: Ну самый обычный же UNION ALL...

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает

Comment: Ну данные для поля "Показатели" придётся ввести вручную как строковые литералы...

Comment: Это как?.......

Comment: ```SELECT 'Наименование показателя' AS `Показатель`, {выражение} AS `Значение` FROM ..```

Comment: Получилось сделать таблицу, но UNION ALL все равно не работает. 
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL SELECT 'Количество абонентов доступа к се' at line 1